# How to read the whole istream correctly?

Tags: c++

Here is a simple code to print all characters of a txt file on screen:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
       int **i;
       int j,k;
       char a;
    ifstream test("test.txt", ios::binary);
    while((a=test.get())!=-1)//if I use "while(!test.eof())" here, how to avoid the output of the last character(-1) to std::cout, or any ostream objects?
    {
   putchar(a);//also change this to putchar(test.get());
    }
       getchar();
}
```

As I noted in the code, if I use "test.eof()" to judge the end of test.txt, I'll always get an extra blank at the end of the output. How to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
int a;
```

The get() function returns an int, not a char - this is the same in C  - when using getchar(), you read into an int variable not  char. So your loop looks like:

```
while( ( a = test.get() ) != EOF )
```

note you want EOF here, not eof(). a version using eof() would look like this:

```
char c;
while( test.get( c ) ) {
   putchar( c );   // or whatever
}

if ( test.eof() ) {
  // Ok, we finished because of end of file
}
else {
  // finished not because of end of file - probably an error
}
```

Comment: Yes I know get() returns an int, and EOF equals to -1.
But what I want to know is when using istream::eof(), how to show the file correctly?

Comment: @LLawler If you know that,. why didn't your code use an int? I've posted an example which uses eof() - note it is a Bad Idea to loop on eof() - it is only intended for diagnosing the stream state after  a read failed.

Comment: OK. I understand you now. 
But I'm wondering why you insisted I use an int? The char type can also be assigned an int value and compared with -1.

Comment: @L.Lawliet You are reading a binary file. If you use a char variable, the first time a byte with the value of 0xff is read (assuming char is signed, which is unspecified in C++) your loop will terminate. That's why in both C and C++ functions like get() and getchar() return an int.

Answer (score 0):

the `get` method will only set the `eof` error bit after an attempt to read past the EOF. That's why you get the extra blank with the `while (!test.eof())` case.
Generally you always have to read past the EOF before detecting that an EOF occurred. Maybe you could do it like this:

```
char c = test.get();
while (!test.eof()) {
    putchar(c);
    c = test.get();
}
```

or rewritten as for:

```
for (char c = test.get(); !test.eof(); c = test.get()) {
    putchar(c);
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is another solution. But is it dispensable to add a variable here? If I just want to use putchar(test.get()) to print every character and don't feel like any other intermediate , any good advice?